# Webcam is not being detected in opencv

Tags: opencv, webcam

I am using opencv 2.3.1a in ubuntu 11.o4.

I installed opencv using: http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/installing-opencv-2-2-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Since I could not use webcam with that installation. I changed "cmake" option from WITH_V4L=OFF to WITH_V4L=ON. But it still does not work.

I tried the following code:

```
#include "cv.h" 
#include "highgui.h" 
#include <stdio.h>  
// A Simple Camera Capture Framework 
int main() {
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0);

if(!capture)
{
    printf("no camera");
    return -1;
}
}
```

And yeah the output is : no camera
I do not know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps mentioned in:

http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/

This solved the problem.